# Jump to specific flag in help/man file

Tags: command-line, man, arguments

Let's say I'm curious about what a specific flag `-T` means for a command `ls`? Is there a way to jump straight to that using `man ls`...?

or, and this is a slightly different question because it's not `man`, is there a commonly accepted way to jump into a command like `git help log` and go straight to the `-S` flag?

Perhaps it's the same answer?!?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that piping `man` though `less` and using the `-p` flag:

> ```
>   -ppattern or --pattern=pattern
>           The -p option on the command line is equivalent to specifying
>           +/pattern; that is, it tells less to start at the first
>           occurrence of pattern in the file.
> ```

Examples:

```
man ls | less -p -T
man git-log | less -p -S
```

Since you'll land inside `less`, the normal navigation keys work, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It easy can be done by adding `less` command to special variable LESS:

```
LESS=+/-T man ls
```

where `/-T` is `less` command `/`find `-T`pattern

Comment: can you please explain this more? Is this an environment variable that **less** looks for? Not sure what's going on here… thx!